# Why this error is occurred on checked working program on my system? about Tensorflow/Keras memory management problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm sure this code doesn't have any problem.
I got this code from my professor, and I checked its work.
But because of some reason, it doesn't work on my system(Anaconda).

```
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=500, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stop])
```

```
Train on 323 samples, validate on 81 samples
Epoch 1/500
 32/323 [=>............................] - ETA: 5sWARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_loss` which is not available. Available metrics are: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-b496e4002de6> in <module>
----> 1 history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=500, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stop])

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    818         workers=workers,
--> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    820 
    821   def evaluate(self,

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    340                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    341                 training_context=training_context,
--> 342                 total_epochs=epochs)
    343             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    344 

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    126         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    127       try:
--> 128         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    129       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    130         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     96     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     97     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 98                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     99 
    100   return execution_function

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    566         xla_context.Exit()
    567     else:
--> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    569 
    570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    630         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    631         # stateless function.
--> 632         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    633     else:
    634       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2361     with self._lock:
   2362       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2363     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2364 
   2365   @property

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1609          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1610                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1611         self.captured_inputs)
   1612 
   1613   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1690       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1691       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1692           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1693     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1694         args,

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    543               inputs=args,
    544               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 545               ctx=ctx)
    546         else:
    547           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~\anaconda3\envs\AINN\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InternalError:  Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(32, 13), b.shape=(13, 64), m=32, n=64, k=13
     [[node sequential/dense/MatMul (defined at <ipython-input-15-b496e4002de6>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_747]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Any idea about solving this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: does it work if you use `monitor='loss'`?

Comment: Are you running anything else on your GPU? See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11812#issuecomment-318429353

Comment: Looks like an issue with the shapes. Can you put model.summary() here?

Comment: Umm Im watching my course. Can it affect to this?

Comment: To Nicolas Gervais, JimmyFails   How do you mean?

Comment: @Sion - you can check gpu-usage with `nvidia-smi`. If there are processes running other than your training code, you could get the error in your question.

Comment: Im using windows 10 I guess because of memory. How can I resize it?

Answer (score 1):

That error often ocurs (atleast on my machine), when there are some kind of memory issues during training with gpu. That happens, as jakub already mentioned in the comments. You might want to restart your kernel and try again. If that does not help, try to decrease the batch size. Also check your gpu memory usage to see if the gpu has memory left (which would prove this).

The machine of your professor might have more gpu memory than yours, unfortunately tensorflow not also shows a proper out of memory exception.

Comment: Suddenly, It works! Why it's happen...?

Comment: What exactly did you do that helped you?

Comment: I don't know... It doesn't work and when I checked my GPU using, Its memory was full. but IDK why, when I try it again, it was work! I experienced this situation before.

Comment: As I said, this is a bug due to the memory management of tensorflow, as far as I can say. Maybe there is a person, why is deeper in the memory management of tensorflow, but if that happens in the future, clear your memory by restarting the kernel. Sometimes, another kernel stucks in the background, taking all the memory. So opening the taskmanager and killing any python process with high memory usage might help also